# Bring Canvas Instance to Front

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am currently working with the awesome library Fabric.js which has thus far met all of my needs until now. I am attempting to create a layering system by adding new instances of fabric.Canvas each with their own objects/properties of course.

I got this idea from Kangax:
https://twitter.com/fabricjs/status/344822078228283392

I am having trouble switching between these layers (canvas instances).

For example, how would I bring one to the front?

```
        // Create two instances of fabric.Cavnas
        var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');


        // On button click, bring canvas 2 to the front
        $( "#switchbutton" ).click(function() {

            // Attempts:

            //fabric.Canvas.bringToFront(canvas2);
            //fabric.Object.opacity(0);
            fabric.Object.bringToFront(canvas2);
            //canvas1.bringToFront(canvas2);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

As I understand you can't do that. You are trying to bring a object to front in canvas. You need to change z-index of canvas to bring it to front

Basically You need to have many different canvas elements and initialize fabricjs as many layers u have.
So for each new layer your create new canvas element and initialize fabricjs

```
var canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas2');
var canvas3 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas3');
```

And then u will have too keep track of your canvas layers and adjust z-index of your layer canvas and upper canvas

### Method 1 (preferable)

Another option would be to keep one canvas and add custom attribute to your obejects "layerId".
So when u create a object :

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ layerId: activeLayerId, radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));
```

And when you switch layers u just disable other layer objects

```
canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
   obj.selectable = obj.layerId == activeLayerId ? true : false;
});
```

Or if u want to bring to front layer objects

```
canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
   if(obj.layerId == activeLayerId) {
       obj.bringForward();
   }

});
```